# Best practice to communicate with Elastic in an application

Tags: oop, elasticsearch, design-patterns, mediator

It will be first time I am going to use Elastic in production.

For databases, I use repository pattern, for example concrete classes of `IOrderRepository`, `IFacetRepository` uses SQL and Mongo drivers to communicate with db.

The application is going to get all the products from Elastic, and I use Elastic REST Api to get data.

What can be the best practice to represent elastic provider(?) in code base?

I can continue using Repository pattern,and create `ProductRepository` that uses `ElasticClient` and make http calls, but I feel it is not a perfect solution.

I also can't create `ProductService` as I don't want any business in the code.
Single responsibility is getting the products from elastic, that's all.

May be [mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) is the right way to implement.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a `ProductRepository` that uses `ElasticClient` internally:

- A `Repository` is an interface to a database and its clients needn't know if its implementation talks to an Relational DB, MongoDB or Elasticsearch. This is exactly what you'd achieve by creating a `ProductRepository` class.
- If, in future, you move from Elasticsearch to another database, such as DynamoDB, you just need to change `ProductRepository` and its clients won't care.

Be wary of Mediator pattern, as you can end up with *God* objects over time.